# How to specify namespace in custom route handler for MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-areas, mvcroutehandler

I have written a custom route handler.  Because I have Areas in my web site with conflicting controller names, I am getting the error: Multiple types were found that match the controller named...

I think I need to specify a namespace in my handler, right?

I have tried the following, none of which work:

```
public class MyRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {

        (... complicated DB lookups and "re-writing" of requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] ...)

        // doesn't work
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["namespaces"] = new[] { "Site.Contollers" };

        // doesn't work
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("namespaces", new[] { "Site.Contollers" });

        // doesn't work
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["namespaces"] = "Site.Contollers";

        // doesn't work
        requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("namespaces", "Site.Contollers");

        (... snip ...)

        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}
```

What is the correct way?

NOTE: Because my handler does database lookups and chooses different controllers based on the results, I cannot use the basic MapRoute() method in my Global.asax.cs file (as far as I know).

Comment: Just checking, are you calling `base.GetHttpHandler` after adding the value to `DataTokens`?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I will add this to my question.

Comment: Are you using a custom controller factory? or the default `BaseControllerFactory`?

Comment: I'm using the default factory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OMG, I'm dumb.

I misspelled "Controllers."  The correct answer is:

```
requestContext.RouteData.DataTokens.Add("namespaces", new string[] { "Site.Controllers" });
```